# Creating a MKPolygon from user-placed annotations in map

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkoverlay

I want the user to be able to create polygons after placing some (unknown number) MKpointAnnotations in the map.I have put a gesture recognizer that gets activated once the user taps a button, and so annotations are placed.But how to use these as corners for a MKPolygon?
Below the code for saving the corners of the polygon.This after some mods I did to it.Now the app crashes and the crash reporter says index out of range.The corners are MKPointAnnotation-s created via a GestureRecognizer.

```
-(IBAction)addCorner:(id)sender
{
NSMutableArray *addCorners = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[addCorners addObject:pointAnnotation];
ptsArray = addCorners;
}

-(IBAction)addPolygonOverlay:(id)sender
{
int cornersNumber = sizeof(ptsArray);
MKMapPoint points[cornersNumber];

for (int i=0; i<cornersNumber; i++) {
    points[i] = MKMapPointForCoordinate([[ptsArray objectAtIndex:i] coordinate]);
}

MKPolygon *polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:cornersNumber];
[mapview addOverlay:polygon];

}
```

Comment: How are you storing the list of corners (annotations) of the polygon?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is the `addCorner` method.  Instead of adding each corner to the `ptsArray` variable, it creates a new array with just the last corner and sets the`ptsArray` equal to that so it only has the one, last corner.

Change the `addCorner` method like this:

```
-(IBAction)addCorner:(id)sender
{
    if (ptsArray == nil)
    {
        self.ptsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    [ptsArray addObject:pointAnnotation];
}
```

Also make sure `ptsArray` is declared and synthesized properly:

```
//in the .h file...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ptsArray;
//in the .m file...
@synthesize ptsArray;
```

(By the way, why not add the corner to `ptsArray` right where the `pointAnnotation` is created instead of in a separate user action?)

Second problem is in the `addPolygonOverlay` method.  You have to use the `NSArray` `count` property to get the number of items in the array.  The `sizeof` function returns the number of bytes of physical memory the passed variable uses.  For `ptsArray` which is a pointer, it will return 4.  If the `ptsArray` has less than 4 items, you will get the "index out of range" exception.

So change

```
int cornersNumber = sizeof(ptsArray);
```

to

```
int cornersNumber = ptsArray.count;
```

Another important thing to note is that the polygon sides will be drawn in the order the points are in the array.  If the user does not add corners in a clockwise or counter-clockwise order, the polygon will look strange.  You could re-create the polygon overlay immediately after a user adds/removes an annotation so they get immediate feedback on how it will look.

Comment: I understand what I was doing wrong.I tried what you said and it worked like a charm!By the way, I think I will do what you said about adding the corner to 'ptsArray' right where the 'pointAnnotation' is created.How silly I was using the 'sizeof' function,I totally forgot the 'count' property'.Thanks for all your help, really precious!

Comment: Can I ask an opinion? I am creating two overlays and using gesture recognizers,,a LongPressure(1sec)_circle) and Tap(poly).The problem is that after I have tapped both buttons that activate these gesture recognizers and the creation of the overlays(first I have done a circle and then a polygon), when i want to create a second circle, I get two pins, one "as a tap" and one after a second...I think to try creating a global gesture recognizer initiaded in the 'viewdidload' method and then "customize" mkmapponits usage locally within button tap-action methods i mentioned before.What do you think?

Comment: You probably want to ask a new question for that but a simple solution is to keep only one gesture recognizer enabled at a time.  When user taps button to create circle, enable long-press-gr and disable tap-gr.  Do the reverse when user taps button to create polygon.  Displaying a label somewhere showing which gr is currently active would be helpful to the user.